# Vim Lookup help for abbreviations

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if there is a way to lookup the description or options for various vim abbreviations with `help`.

For example, if an experienced vim user found this in a .vimrc they would know it was setting the shift width to 4

```
set sw=4
```

However, running `help sw` brings up the help for the swap file, as that is what the sw *command* does. I sometimes find myself running into these shortcut/abbreviations in other vimrc's and it is difficult to find the documentation on them. What I typically do is try `help` and if that doesn't work I do a find for it surrounded by single quotes like so:

```
/'sw'
```

But I assume there has to be a better way to do so. I'm also not sure what the proper term for these "abbreviations" are which may have been why I was unsuccessful in a Google search.

Comment: Please see `:h help-summary`. Required reading, everybody ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put sw in quotes so that the help jumps to the setting

```
:help 'sw'
```

Comment: Haha, duh. I think I tried double quotes one time. Don't know why I never thought of this. Thanks

Comment: Don't waste keystrokes: `:h 'sw`.